# Uploading bulk files from local system to SharePoint online using PowerShell script throwing an error you cannot call null valued expression

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

My requirement is to upload multiple files using PowerShell script to SharePoint online.

while uploading files to a folder in the SharePoint document library, it showing me this error.

I am extracting only file name before uploading and create a folder with that filename and want to upload the file in that particular folder using PowerShell script .

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"



### Variables for Processing

$WebUrl = "https://tanviteddu.sharepoint.com/sites/Powershell/"

$LibraryName ="Documents"

$ListURL="/sites/Powershell/Shared Documents/Reports"

$SourceFolder="C:\Hari Priya"



#Setup Credentials to connect

$Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force))



#Set up the context

$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($WebUrl)

$Context.Credentials = $Credentials



#Get the Library

$Library =  $Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)



#upload each file from the directory

Foreach ($File in  (dir $SourceFolder -File))

{


$fn=(Split-path -Path $file -Leaf).Split(".")[0];

Try 

{

  #Set up the context

    $Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteUrl)
    $Context.Credentials = $credentials

    #Get the List Root Folder
    $ParentFolder=$Context.web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl($ListURL)

    #sharepoint online powershell create folder
    $Folder = $ParentFolder.Folders.Add($fn)
    $ParentFolder.Context.ExecuteQuery()

    Write-host "New Folder Created Successfully!" -ForegroundColor Green
}
catch 
{

 write-host "Error: $($_.Exception.Message)" -foregroundcolor Red
}




 #Get the file from disk

    $FileStream = ([System.IO.FileInfo] (Get-Item $File.FullName)).OpenRead()



$FinalUrl=$ListURL+"\"+$fn+"\"+$file

#Upload the File to SharePoint Library

    $FileCreationInfo = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation

$FileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true

$FileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $FileStream

$FileCreationInfo.URL = $File

$FileUploaded = $FinalUrl.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)


#powershell to upload files to sharepoint online

$Context.Load($FileUploaded)

$Context.ExecuteQuery()


#Close file stream

$FileStream.Close()

write-host "File: $($File) has been uploaded!"

}
```

While uploading, it is showing the error as below:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. 
At line:26 char:5

+     $FileUploaded = $FinalUrl.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeExceptio
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot find an overload for "Load" and the argument count: "1".
At line:28 char:5

+     $Context.Load($FileUploaded)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

The below is working code - upload files from local drive to SharePoint online using PowerShell CSOM:

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
#Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
cls



$fileName = "File_Uploading_Report"
#'yyyyMMddhhmm   yyyyMMdd
$enddate = (Get-Date).tostring("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
#$filename =  $enddate + '_VMReport.doc'  
$logFileName = $fileName +"_"+ $enddate+"_Log.txt"   
$invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation).Value  
$directoryPath = Split-Path $invocation.MyCommand.Path  

$directoryPathForLog=$directoryPath+"\"+"LogFiles"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForLog))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForLog
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   


#$logPath = $directoryPath + "\" + $logFileName 

$logPath = $directoryPathForLog + "\" + $logFileName 

$isLogFileCreated = $False 



#DLL location

$directoryPathForDLL=$directoryPath+"\"+"Dependency Files"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForDLL))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForDLL
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#DLL location

$clientDLL=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
$clientDLLRuntime=$directoryPathForDLL+"\"+"Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path $clientDLL
Add-Type -Path $clientDLLRuntime


#Files to upload location

$directoryPathForFileToUploadLocation=$directoryPath+"\"+"Files To Upload"
if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPathForFileToUploadLocation))  
        {  
            New-Item -ItemType directory -Path $directoryPathForFileToUploadLocation
            #Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        } 

#Files to upload location ends here.



function Write-Log([string]$logMsg)  
{   
    if(!$isLogFileCreated){   
        Write-Host "Creating Log File..."   
        if(!(Test-Path -path $directoryPath))  
        {  
            Write-Host "Please Provide Proper Log Path" -ForegroundColor Red   
        }   
        else   
        {   
            $script:isLogFileCreated = $True   
            Write-Host "Log File ($logFileName) Created..."   
            [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
            Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
        }   
    }   
    else   
    {   
        [string]$logMessage = [System.String]::Format("[$(Get-Date)] - {0}", $logMsg)   
        Add-Content -Path $logPath -Value $logMessage   
    }   
} 



#The below function will upload the file from local directory to SharePoint Online library.

Function FileUploadToSPOnlineLibrary()
{
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SPOSiteURL,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $File,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $TargetLibrary,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $UserName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string] $Password
    )

    Try 
    {

        $securePassword= $Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force  
        #Setup the Context
        $ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SPOSiteURL)
        $ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($UserName, $securePassword)

        $list = $ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($TargetLibrary)
        $ctx.Load($list)
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery()     

        $tarGetFilePath=$siteURL+"/"+"$TargetLibrary"+"/"+$File

        $fileOpenStream = New-Object IO.FileStream($SourceFilePath, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open)  
        $fileCreationInfo = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FileCreationInformation  
        $fileCreationInfo.Overwrite = $true  
        $fileCreationInfo.ContentStream = $fileOpenStream  
        $fileCreationInfo.URL = $File  
        $uploadFileInfo = $list.RootFolder.Files.Add($FileCreationInfo)  
        $ctx.Load($uploadFileInfo)  
        $ctx.ExecuteQuery() 


        Write-host -f Green "File '$SourceFilePath' has been uploaded to '$tarGetFilePath' successfully!"
    }
    Catch 
    {

            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in uploading File!: " +$tarGetFilePath
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 


    }
}

#Variables
$siteURL="https://globalsharepoint.sharepoint.com/sites/TestSite/"
$listName="TestDocumentLibrary"
$fromDate="2019-10-28"
$toDate="2019-11-09"
$filesFolderLoaction=$directoryPathForFileToUploadLocation;
$userName = "YourSPOAccount@YourTenantDomain.com"
$password = "YourPassWord"
$securePassword= $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

#Variables ends here.


$filesCollectionInSourceDirectory=Get-ChildItem $filesFolderLoaction -File   

$uploadItemCount=1;

    #Extract the each file item from the folder.
    ForEach($oneFile in $filesCollectionInSourceDirectory)
    {            

            try
            {                            

                FileUploadToSPOnlineLibrary -SPOSiteURL $siteURL -SourceFilePath $oneFile.FullName -File $oneFile -TargetLibrary $listName -UserName $UserName -Password $Password

                $fileUploadingMessage=$uploadItemCount.ToString()+": "+$oneFile.Name; 
                Write-Host $fileUploadingMessage -BackgroundColor DarkGreen
                Write-Log $fileUploadingMessage

        $uploadItemCount++

        }
        catch
        { 
            $ErrorMessage = $_.Exception.Message +"in: " +$oneFile.Name
            Write-Host $ErrorMessage -BackgroundColor Red
            Write-Log $ErrorMessage 

        }

    }
    Write-Host "========================================================================"
    Write-Host "Total number of files uploaded: " $filesCollectionInSourceDirectory.Count 
    Write-Host "========================================================================"
```

**Reference URL:**
https://global-sharepoint.com/powershell/upload-files-to-sharepoint-online-document-library-using-powershell-csom/

Comment: Any other ans or suggestion on above question.